# req.cookies returns [Object: null prototype] {} while cookie is visible in browser

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, jwt, mern

I am trying to make a reservation system for a holiday home for my college exams with react, express and mongodb. This is the stack I used during my internship but at school we use laravel so I currently have no one to ask and I have been stuck on this for days
[user roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJrxg.png)

When I am trying to get all users for display in the admin panel it denies the access in the verifyadmin function, when I remove it from the route it does show the users.

[Verify admin function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELClP.png)
[verify token function that is nested in the verify admin function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/471fl.png)

When I console.log the req.cookies it returns [Object: null prototype] {} and when I add the nextfunction in the else condition in the verify admin function it proceeds so the problem must be with the cookie.
[Cookie shows in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrXM2.png)

I read here that adding a proxy to the package.json file instead of fetching from the api endpoint directly could solve it.
However when I do this the fetch function uses the localhost route from the frontend and still works, also if I use the wrong end point in the proxy, which I really can't wrap my head around.

[api index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEFFu.png)

Please help me pass my exams, please let me know if you need anymore info

I tried to show a list of users when the logged in user isAdmin: true via cookies however the cookie returns empty

Comment: Please don't add images of code, and add your snippets as text to your question

Comment: Oh sorry , I ll edit